# CodeIgniter Community Auth redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've installed Community Auth but after several hours of triels and errors I still can't be able to get it working!
The problem is that after having created the test uer and tried to login I am redirect to an non-sense url.
Let's say my test site is at http://test.webintenerife.com. Here I have put an app just to test Community Auth. I followed all installation steps and I've succesfully created my test user.

My config base_url is 'test.webintenerife.com'. Try to login at http://test.webintenerife.com/Examples/login but redirect url is
http://test.webintenerife.com/Examples/test.webintenerife.com/test.webintenerife.com/login?redirect=Examples/simple_verification

My .htaccess is:

```
`    #MAKE SURE TO LEAVE THE NEXT TWO LINES HERE.
#BEGIN DENY LIST --
#END DENY LIST --
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
#condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]`
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My base_url was wrong, as it was the first time I use CI. It should be 'http://test.webintenerife.com/' :-(